# How to provide the Terraform Cloud API token using an environment variable?

Tags: terraform

In my CI environment (Bitbucket pipelines) I'm trying to use the new Terraform Cloud remote state management. The announcement [video](https://youtu.be/ZGl8wlxlcIU?t=120) clearly states you can use environment variables instead of the `.terraformrc` file to pass your API token. However, I cannot find any documentation on the exact environment variable I have to use.

I followed the [getting started](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud/tf_cloud_gettingstarted) guide about Terraform Cloud, but there they also don't mention anything about environment variables.

I also looked at the environment variables section of the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html), but there was also no mentioning of how to set (or override) the cli configuration.

Comment: Could you add the commands you used to the Q&A to prevent that they get lost if the links get deprecated?

Comment: What version of terraform do you use?

Comment: So you created an account on [terraform enterprise](https://app.terraform.io/session)?

Comment: Did you check the issue list or create an issue on the [terraform github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform)?

Comment: @030, I did check the github issues before posting a question here, however asking the question here seemed more logical.

Comment: @030, I created an account on Terraform Cloud

Comment: @030, I used version v0.12.4

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with environment variables of the form `TF_TOKEN_${sanitized_hostname}`.

For example for Terraform Cloud:

```
export TF_TOKEN_app_terraform_io=xxxxxx.atlasv1.zzzzzzzzzzzzz

terraform apply
```

This takes precedence over any `terraform login` or `.tfrc` file.
It is documented under the [developer CLI config](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#environment-variable-credentials) pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Terraform Cloud/Enterprise provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe/latest/docs), you could set the `TFE_TOKEN` environment variable.

Alternatively, you could write the terraform config file temporarily during the build, e.g.:

```sh
# Set environment variable
MY_TF_TOKEN='abc.123.abc123'

# Create .terraformrc with credential config for user
cat >~/.terraformrc <<EOL
credentials "app.terraform.io" {
  token = "${TF_CLOUD_TOKEN}"
}
EOL
```

Otherwise, you could (but not recommended) manipulate the `credentials.tfrc.json`  in `~/.terraform.d` but beware that this may be overwritten when running terraform commands.  For example using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) in bash:

```sh
# Set environment variable
MY_TF_TOKEN='abc.123.abc123'

# Create json from environment variable and (over)write expected file 
jq --arg token $MY_TF_TOKEN \
    '{"credentials":{"app.terraform.io":{"token": $token}}}' \
    > ~/.terraform.d/credentials.tfrc.json
```

You should get the following when e.g. running `cat ~/.terraform.d/credentials.tfrc.json`:

```json
{
  "credentials": {
    "app.terraform.io": {
      "token": "abc.123.abc123"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the video they don't specify whether terraform expects a certain variable of not.
One thing you can do however, is use the method to pass arbitrary environment variables, as long as their name starts with TF_VAR_ (example: TF_VAR_myvar). Then in your terraform files (in this example the terraformrc file) declare the variable with this line:

```
variable myvar {}
```

Then you can use it instead of hardcoded token value with this syntax: `${var.myvar}`

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I'll try and let you know!

Comment: So I tried and (after reading the documentation) agreed it should work, but it sadly does not.

Answer (score 0):

I want to contribute to this topic with 2 articles that helped me to configure my Azure Pipelines to log in to Terraform Cloud and download Modules hosted in a Private Registry in Terraform Cloud.

https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-configure-azure-devops-with-terraform-enterprise-cac1bbd9810b
https://mikehacker.dev/blog/configuring-terraform-enterprise-credentials-to-work-with-azure-devops/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/517884)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).